# Grails Unit Test Comparing String Encoding Error

Tags: unit-testing, grails, encoding, utf-8, groovy

I have this unit test below that fails due to probably an encoding problem which I couldn't figure how to solve. Both the class and messages.properties files are UTF-8 encoded. I checked in file properties inside eclipse.

```
assert mobileResponse.toMobile().data.get('mobile_error_description') == 'Usuário e/ou senha inexistentes e/ou inválidos.'
```

The console output is:

```
assert mobileResponse.toMobile().data.get('mobile_error_description') == "Usu√°rio e/ou senha inexistentes e/ou inv√°lidos."
                                                                      |false
```

Comment: Could be this bug? http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6813